# OAuth2 requires a return URL, but I have none to give. Windows 8 Phone development

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a project that uses an API to access some data. The API requests a return url so that when it has authenticated, it can send the information back to a URL... However, on a phone... what URL do I provide for the data to return to?

This application is a windows 8 phone app written in C# in Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Any ideas? I really don't know enough about it...

This is the documentation I'm working with: https://developers.podio.com/authentication/username_password